# How to remove query string stores in python cgi FieldStorage

Tags: python, cgi

I am using python cgi to write a login and logout web page and now i am having difficulties in the logout part. Having used cgi.FieldStorage to store my parameters, I have no idea how to update or remove the parameters inside.

Comment: Did you try anything? Show us your code where you are facing problem. Check this link. http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lab2q/lesson_7/

Comment: For example, if I use url:"xxxx?user_id=abc&password=123". These two parameters user_id and password would be stored in cgi.FieldStorage once I have successfully logged in. What I want to do is remove these two parameters and be able to log out.